# Crear un array a partir de un for

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando crear el contenido de un array a partir de un bucle `for`. Os dejo con el código:

```
$prodlang = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_post WHERE wp_pedmin!=0");
$tama= count($prodlang);

$product_min_qty = array( 

    for($i=0;$i<$tama;$i++){
        if ($i+1==$tama || $i+1>$tama){
            array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin)
        } else {
            array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin),      
        }
    }
);
```

Intento crear el contenido de `$product_min_qty` pero muere en el script. ¿Qué se me escapa?

Answer (score 2):

El código presenta varios errores importantes:

- No puedes tener un bucle `for` dentro de la definición de un `array`
- Parece que quieres simular un operador ternario, pero te faltan partes (en concreto la más importante que sería la asignación)
- Las operaciones en PHP se separan con punto y coma, y no con coma o sin nada.

Para solucionar esos problemas deberías:

- Definir la variable `$product_min_qty` como un array vacío
- Crear un bucle y rellenar la variable dentro de ese bucle
- Las dos partes del `if..else`  son iguales, podrías simplificarlas directamente o, si van a ser diferentes, usar un operador ternario para definir cada parte
- Como indica [Genarito en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46629/crear-un-array-a-partir-de-un-for/46635?noredirect=1#comment81352_46635), la condición del `if` se puede simplificar porque la segunda parte (`$i+1>$tama`) siempre será falsa por los valores del bucle `for`.

Algo como esto (no lo he probado y puede contener errores):

```
$prodlang = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_post WHERE wp_pedmin!=0");
$tama= count($prodlang);
$product_min_qty = array() 

for($i=0;$i<$tama;$i++){
    $product_min_qty[] = ($i+1 == $tama) ?
                         array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin) :
                         array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin);
}
```

Como te ponía en un comentario que borré, te recomendaría que mientras estás desarrollando usases `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de la página para ver qué errores tienes, porque te sería de gran ayuda para identificar y solucionar problemas como los del código compartido.

Comment: Solo un pequeño comentario para el usuario que pregunta, la condición `$i+1>$tama` es inútil por la condición del `for()`

Comment: Cierto. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadirlo. Gracias por añadir esa nota

Answer (score 1):

**No** puedes realizar un `for` dentro de un `array`, ya que esto generaría un error de *sintaxis*, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$prodlang = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_post WHERE wp_pedmin != 0");
$tama= count($prodlang);

$product_min_qty = array(); // Inicializas tu array

for($i=0;$i<$tama;$i++){ // Realizas el for 
    if ($i+1==$tama || $i+1>$tama){
        // Haces un push de acuerdo a tus condiciones
        $product_min_qty[] = array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin); 
    } else {
        // Haces un push de acuerdo a tus demás condiciones
        $product_min_qty[] = array( 'id' => $prodlang[$i]->ID , 'min' => $prodlang[$i]->wp_pedmin); 
    }
}
```

Y ya para ver el resultado de este puedes hacer un simple:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($product_min_qty);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a poner algo parecido a lo que pides con un ejemplo

```
$array = call_user_func(function() use ($variablesaUsar) {
   // aqui pones el for rellenando un array temporal.
   return $arrayRelleno; // devuelves el array temporal y se asignara a tu     array antes creado llamado $array.
});
```